# Filing a VAT report on exports from EU to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, vat, brexit

I'm exporting services (no goods) from the Czech Republic to the UK. Until now, based on the Czech and EU regulations, I put no VAT charges on the invoices; however, I still had to report the amount of services exported in a VIES report (EC Sales List). (The report mentions both my VAT#, the customer's VAT# and the price.)

With Brexit, from what I undestand, the UK is leaving the EU VAT area: https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/uk_withdrawal_en

Does this mean that for any invoices after December 31st 2020, I don't have to include the exports to the UK into my VIES reports?